# How to delete all images from all sheets of a Libreoffice Calc Workbook

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have a Libreoffice Calc workbook with over 60 sheets many of which have heavy images that were copied to them. I would like to delete all of the images with a Calc Basic macro.
I have tried the following which fails with a Basic runtime error saying `Property or method not found: Pictures.`

```
Sub DeleteAllPics()
    Dim Pic As Object
    For Each Pic In ThisComponent.CurrentController.ActiveSheet.Pictures
       Pic.Delete
Next Pic
End Sub
```

I have also tried the following which fails with Basic runtime error `Object variable not set.`

```
Sub deleteAllPics()
    Dim wkSheet As Object
    For Each wkSheet In ThisWorkbook.ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName()
        Dim Pict As Object
        For Each Pict In wkSheet
            Pict.Delete
        Next Pict
    Next wkSheet       
End Sub
```

The following code will remove all pictures from all pages of a Libreoffice Writer document:

```
   Sub RemoveImages
       Dim oDoc as Object
       oDoc = ThisComponent
       Dim oGraphics as Object
       oGraphics = oDoc.getGraphicObjects()
       Dim oImg as Object
       For Each oImg in oGraphics
       oDoc.getText().removeTextContent(oImg)
       Next 
    End Sub
```

I need a code that will work like the above one to remove all images from all sheets of a Calc workbook. Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For spreadsheets, you need to obtain the [XDrawPage](https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/drawing/XDrawPage.html) for each sheet.

Here is proper LibreOffice Basic code.  In LibreOffice parlance, it's called a spreadsheet or a document, not a workbook.  Also `For Each` is borrowed from VBA and does not work for XDrawPage.  (Sheets could be enumerated with `For Each`, but to be consistent, the standard `For` loop is preferred.)

```vb
Sub DeleteAllPics()
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oDrawPage As Object
    Dim oShape As Object
    Dim iShape As Integer
    Dim iSheet As Integer
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    For iSheet = 0 To oDoc.getSheets().getCount() - 1
        oDrawPage = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(iSheet).getDrawPage()
        For iShape = oDrawPage.getCount() - 1 To 0 Step -1
            oShape = oDrawPage.getByIndex(i)
            oDrawPage.remove(oShape)
        Next iShape
    Next iSheet
End Sub
```